# NSFetchedResultsController, sectionNameKeyPath, and sections for dates without data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` using a Core Data data source on iOS.  The items are date-sorted events.  I'm already using `sectionNameKeyPath` to split events into sections by date.  All there is good.

I would like to include section headers for dates in which data does not exist in the database.  For example:

```
-August 14-
Event One
Event Two
-August 15-
-August 16-
Event Three
```

Since no event exists for August 15 in the above example, the August 15 section header currently does not appear.  I would like it to appear.

I've considered including "mock" objects for dates in which no events occur, and simply not displaying them for rows in the table.  Possible, but lots of extra processing (all row heights need to be calculated before display - this could easily have thousands of objects).  Another option is to include one mock object in all sections, where I could compensate equally across all rows (less processing).  This should work, but I'm really not interested in junking up my database with mock objects.

Any suggestions on a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing what the dates represent (current dates or past dates) this solution may or may not work well. But what about creating a table that handles the dates. Then have a one to many relationship to the objects: date <-->> event.

Then when the app launches you could add the dates you need. Then the fetched controller just pulls out all of the dates in the dates table, these could be the sections. For the rows you could just access the date's events.

Now the main downfall I see from this is that you may not get the best functionality from the fetched controller, although every time you access the relationship the information should be up-to-date. Besides this I cannot think of a smooth solution, but I would personally be leery of adding junk data to my database.

Comment: I had this general idea in the back of my head as well.  I've yet to delve into one-to-many relationships on a NSFetchResultsController.  Should the controller be able to pull out all event records this way, or do I need to pull them out manually (separate fetch requests) for each section?

Comment: @MitchCohen no you can access the relationship for this information dateObject.events will give you all the events on that date (assuming you setup your coredata model this way). Do you really need the functionality of a FetchedResultController for the dates?